# How to use Poco Logger

Tags: logging, global, poco

I am new to Poco, I saw following example in Poco online help:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AutoPtr<SimpleFileChannel> pChannel(new SimpleFileChannel);
    pChannel->setProperty("path", "sample.log");
    pChannel->setProperty("rotation", "2 K");
    Logger::root().setChannel(pChannel);
    Logger& logger = Logger::get("TestLogger"); // inherits root channel
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        logger.information("Testing SimpleFileChannel");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a global logger which can be used in other functions and classes in my application as well (sample code is below).
In the above example, logger is declared and initialized in main, I can't use it in `myClass` if I don't pass logger to `myFun` (I don't want passing logger as a argument, it looks awkward, as I will need to use logger throughout the application, in multiple files); I tried this way: put `Logger& logger = Logger::get("TestLogger");` outside `main()`, as global variable, all the other parts in main remain the same, however this doesn't work, sample.log is not generated after I run the application. I can't do this way: just declare `Logger& logger` outside the function, then initialize it in `main()` because logger is a reference which must be initialized when declared. How to do it?

```
class myClass
{
public:
     myClass() { }
     ~myClass() { }
     myFun() { /*calling logger...*/ } 
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AutoPtr<SimpleFileChannel> pChannel(new SimpleFileChannel);
    pChannel->setProperty("path", "sample.log");
    pChannel->setProperty("rotation", "2 K");
    Logger::root().setChannel(pChannel);
    Logger& logger = Logger::get("TestLogger"); // inherits root channel
    logger.information("starting up");

    myClass aClass;
    aClass.myFun();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't `Logger::get()` grant access to a global pool of `Logger` objects, as a singleton?

What happens if you run your code snippet above, i.e. when you initialize your logger in `main()` and reference it in `myClass::myFun()` via `Logger::get( "TestLogger" )`? That should work just fine.

Of course you don't have access to `main()`s `Logger&`reference in `myClass::myFun()`, but you should be able to reach it through `Logger::get()`.